# Platform Events Subscription through Trigger and parsing a JSON payload field

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, platform-event

We are going to implement platform events for inbound integration and subscribe to events using trigger. Among the platform event object, one of the fields is a long text area which has a JSON payload from external app. We have to deserialize this field and update some fields on a custom object based on externalId.

Here is what I tried so far,

Created a platform event object Test_PE__e and field Payload__c which should update

Example JSON Payload we may receive:

```
{
  "Customer__c": 
{
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Test2",
    "externalId": "10339483"
    "sId":"12344",
    "status":"In Progress",
      “subStatus”:”Waiting for Allowance to be Cleared”,
     "statusType":"Update",
    }
  }
```

---

```
trigger customerInboundTrigger on Test_PE__e (after Insert) {

    for(Test_PE__e e: Trigger.new){
      // how to call wrapper class or update customer info         
    }
}
```

---

JSON2APEX Class from this utility https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public Customer__c Customer__c;

    public class Customer__c {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String externalId;
        public String sId;
        public String status;
        public String subStatus;
        public String statusType;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

------then a wrapper class-------------------------

```
public class CustomerInboundWrapper {

     public JSON2Apex wrapper {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void updateCustomer(){

//do updates here

}
}
```

Is this the right approach to consume json payload using platform events subscription?

If yes how can I update Status__c, Sub_Status__c and Status_Type__c fields on customer correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to modify payload to match it to Salesforce Object structure like following

```
{
"External_Id__c": "10339483"
"Status__c":"In Progress",
"Sub_Status__":"Waiting for Allowance to be Cleared",
 "Status_Type__c ":"Update",
}
```

and then just execute the following code in trigger

```
trigger Test_Pe_Trigger on Test_PE__e (after Insert) {
    List<Customer__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Customer__c>();
    for(Test_PE__e e: Trigger.new){
        recordsToUpdate.add( (Customer__c) JSON.deserialize( e.Payload__c, Customer__c.class ) );
    }
    update recordsToUpdate Customer__c.External_Id__c;
}
```